# order_by creates duplicate entries

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have 4 model classes: User, Stack, Article and Rating. Users can create stacks, add articles, put them on a stack, rate the articles and share the stacks.
I want to get a QuerySet of all articles of a specific stack (got by pk) and ordered by the current users rating. My query leads to duplicate entries in my QuerySet if the stack was shared and an article was rated by another user, so that there exists a rating object for an article twice:

```
qs = stack.article_set.all().order_by("ratings__rating", "-pk")
```

#### models:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        Article,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='ratings'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='ratings'
    )
    rating = models.IntegerField()


class Stack(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Article(models.Model):
    stack = models.ForeignKey(Stack, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    text = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

How can I get the ordered QuerySet without the duplicates, just ordered by the request.user ratings.

## Update

What I do for now is to query twice. One time to get the already rated article objects ordered by the rating and a second time to get the currently not rated article objects unsorted.

```
    context['rated_articles'] = deck.article_set.filter(
        ratings__user__exact=self.request.user
        ).order_by("ratings__rating", "-pk")

    context['not_rated_articles'] = deck.article_set.all().exclude(
        ratings__user__exact=self.request.user
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to filter the article set before you order it, based on the stacks owner

```
user = stack.owner
stack.article_set.filter(rating__user__exact=user).order_by("ratings__rating", "-pk")
```

Comment: No, but I tried it now and calling `stack.article_set.all().order_by("ratings__rating", "-pk").distict()` just cuts the articles that are rated by another user with the same rating. If the other user has a different rating than the current user it won't distinct the objects.

Comment: I see what you mean. I think you may always have duplicates in your query set when trying to order by rating, since there can be multiple ratings for a single article. Maybe just return the article queryset un ordered, and then write some code to manually sort them by rating? But then you have the problem of choosing which rating you use when there is more than one for an article

Comment: Try passing 'article_id' as an argument to distinct

Comment: This return `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend` because I use MySQL and not PostgreSQL. But I think this way it wouldn't distinct always the correct objects. It just checks for duplicates of `article_id` and not checking if the rating object is from the `request.user`.

Comment: This way it filters correctly, but one limitation is that I need to get all articles even if they are currently not rated by the request.user.
Now I do another query by excluding the already rated objects.